# Need JavaScript to reset an images source back to original when a button is clicked, after going through a script which swapped the source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am currently running JavaScript in my html document successfully which allows me to swap a main-img on hovering over various thumbnails. I have these successfully working in various modal windows with different selections of images within each modal window.

My issue is that after I hover over an image and the 'main-img' changes to the respective thumbnail, When I then then close this window and open a different modal window the 'main-img' has remained that from the previous swap in the previous modal window.

this is the javascript being used for the 'image swap':

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Image swap on hover
  $("div#gallery li img").hover(function() {
    $('img#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
  });
  // Image preload
  var imgSwap = [];
  $("div#gallery li img").each(function() {
    imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
    imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
  });
  $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
}
```

I attempted to fix the issue by creating a secondary script which reloads or resets the 'main-img's source back to the original for each modal on a button click which opens the respective modals. However I am only recently self learning jquery and java-script so haven't got to grips with the complexities of the code so there are likely some obvious errors or better ways to approach this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // script reset and reload
  $("button.md-trigger").click(
    function(){
      $('img#main-img').attr('src','2.jpg');
  });
});
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

updated code still not working :

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var $mainImg = $('img#main-img');

            $mainImg.data('originalSrc', $mainImg.attr('src'));
            $("div#gallery li img").hover(function(){
            $mainImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
        }); 
         $("button.md-trigger").click(
            function(){
                $mainImg.attr('src', $mainImg.data('originalSrc'));
        });
        }
```

Comment: So does the button click code not work?

Comment: no the button click does not work in the attended way, and there maybe a better approach to the issue. I need the button to reset the src to the original not a tagged .jpg like in my code.

Comment: So you need to store it to what it is. Hard to tell from the code what it would be.

Comment: My basic issue is that when moving from one modal window to another, the image from the previous window is appearing in place of where the 'main-img' for that modal window should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it off into a data element.

```
var $mainImg = $('img#main-img');

$mainImg.data('originalSrc', $mainImg.attr('src'));
$("div#gallery li img").hover(function(){
  $mainImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
});
```

Then when you want to change it back, replace the src with the `$mainImg.data('originalSrc')`

Comment: where would this go in reference to the existing code?

Comment: If `$('img#main-img').attr('src','2.jpg');` is your "reset" line, then `'2.jpg'` would be replaced by the `$mainImg.data('originalSrc')` command, as I mentioned in the last line of the answer.  Where ever you are trying to reset it, that's where you'd use that command.

Comment: could u confirm if this is right, it hasn't yet fixed my issue but it maybe be implementing it incorrectly, as I have quite got the grasp of writing JavaScript yet, and can only currently do basic editing.  I have entered the first part of your code into  my javascript and then put this in:                $("button.md-trigger").click(
        function(){
           $('img#main-img').attr('src', $mainImg.data('originalSrc'));
      });
      }

Comment: @ReganBoyce  looks right, but change `$('img#main-img').attr('src', $mainImg.data('originalSrc'));` to `$mainImg.attr('src', $mainImg.data('originalSrc'));`  `$mainImg` is already the element, so no need to look it up again.

Comment: im going to add my current code as an edit to the bottom of my question because it's unfortunately still not working, it is potentially me making yet another mistake, thanks for your help thus far

Comment: so the current issue is this fix seems to resolve the first modal, it resets the main-img for my first modal window, however the second modal window now automatically takes on the main-img of the first modal

Comment: Wait, what?  No dude, you duplicated your hover logic.  Don't do that.  Just add the setting of the data field above your top over block.  @ReganBoyce

Comment: I've updated my scripts and it works great for the first modal, however the second modal is now using the main image of the 1st. From what I understand of the script I assume it is saving the data of the 'main-img' from the first modal and therefore for every new modal window the click function is then placing that saved source into 'main-img' slot on every window. I need code which somehow recognise that every modal has a different original source. Unless there is a way to have the click perform a function which undoes or resets any changes to the sources rather than a specific data source.